# Открытие одной и той же страницы с разными параметрами

Tags: javascript, html

Здравия! Попалась вот такая задачка.
Есть несколько посадочных страниц на некоем сайте под управлением некоей CMS. При нажатии на ссылку на этих страницах происходит адресация на главную страницу с несколькими шагами выбора, а именно: выбираем нечто из выпадающего списка, жмем далее и т.п.. Вопрос вот в чем: возможно ли в принципе каким-то образом распознать с какой из этих страниц мы пришли и, самое главное, сделать так, чтобы при этом уже был выбран нужный select и нажата кнопка "Далее", то есть переход сразу ко второму шагу?

Comment: Подключить Гугл аналитику

Comment: Но ведь она мне позволит только понимать с какой из страниц я пришел. А нужно с продолжением, чтобы, в зависимости от того, откуда я, выполнялся нужный сценарий. На одной и той же странице

Comment: Очень все она позволяет, настроить просто нужно )))) может мы о разных вещах говорим, правда

Comment: Был бы крайне признателен за более подробную информацию, или, хотя бы, за ссылку на нее)

Comment: Вариант 1 - `document.referrer` - но тут есть тонкости. Вариант 2 - `location.search` или `location.hash`, но здесь вам нужно будет сделать разные ссылки на разных страницах.

Answer (score -1):

Привет попробуй дать с иной страницы при переходе значение ID (domain.com/index.php?id=1) ... и так далее...

Comment: Попробую сформулировать проще: нужно заставить выполнение сценария А только при переходе со страницы А. Сценарий Б со страницы Б и так далее. Как это осуществить? Передавать целую функцию в адресе ведь нельзя, кажется?

Comment: смотри. Даешь сценарию А id 1 -- b - id 2 ... 

Затем при переходе пишешь страницу... 

пример

(Cценарий а) 

$id = 1; 

<a href="/link.php?'.$id.'"> one </a> 

Сценарий Б 

$id = 2; 
<a href="/link.php?'.$id.'"> one </a> 

-------------------------------------------------

Теперь на странице link.php... 

$ids = $_GET['id'];

if($ids = 1){ Сценарий 1 }
if($ids = 2) {сценарий 2} .....

Comment: Вариант. Спасибо, буду пробовать)